# pandas.read_excel() output OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using ubuntu 18.04, pandas==1.2.1

my excel file looks something like this

```
seq           userid      point     .....
2.01e^+12       A        231231.15
2.012e^+12      B          123
2.0131e^+12     C           3
2.41e^+12       D         2312
2.41e^+12       E         31.15
```

max(seq) = 2.41e^+12
max(point) = 231231.15

When I to `pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx")` it outputs error message in the title.

From resources:

1. [OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long torchtext.datasets.text_classification.DATASETS['AG_NEWS']()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988897/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-torchtext-datasets-text) -> tells me I need to change csv.field_size_limit to sys.maxsize however couldn't find out how to change excel.field_size_limit
2. ["OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" on windows but not mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma) -> tells me I need to set `seq, point` columns to float datatype. which i did using `pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx", converters={'seq':float, "point":float})` however didn't fix.

When I remove two float columns I can read excel file. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you clarify resources #1. Not sure what you mean by you "couldn't figure out how to change r"

Comment: @user1558604 edited, thanks!

Comment: do you know what the maximum value is in each column? And are they ints or floats?

Comment: #2 should have worked, but if they are ints I would use dtype of "UInt64" rather than float.

Comment: @user1558604 I've edited max values and `converters={"seq":"UInt64"}) still outputs same error message.

Comment: Oh, don't use `converters` use `dtype`. I believe with dtype set, the value is read in as that dtype. If converter is set I think it reads in as default then it attempts to convert.

Comment: @user1558604 are you saying use dtype like `pd.read_excel(dtype="UInt64")` ? it outputs same error message and also same with dtype=str, int, and float

Comment: Yeah, that should have worked... Are you using 32 bit python or 64?

Comment: @user1558604 I am using 64bit.

Comment: @haneulkim i am facing the same issue. how did you fix ?

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, excel assigned a date type to a number column and pandas was trying to convert a 13 digits number to date. Changing the data type in excel from "date" to "general" solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the options for importing data on pydata.org you'll options like *convert_dates=True* you can toggle these on or off until your file reads. Assuming the problematic data is a date.